# How to change ImageView of dice roller based on random result

Tags: java, android, imageview, dice

I am building a Fate Dice roller app for my finishing course in App Development and I am having a problem with changing the ImageView of the dice based on the result. Here is the code(the roller is in a fragment tab):

```
public class RollDiceFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button btnRoll;
    private EditText et_rollDice;
    private ImageView iv_dice1, iv_dice2, iv_dice3, iv_dice4;
    Random random;


    public RollDiceFragment() {
    }


    public static RollDiceFragment newInstance() {
        RollDiceFragment fragment = new RollDiceFragment();
        return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rolldice, container, false);
        random = new Random();
        btnRoll = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnRoll);
        et_rollDice = rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_rollDice);
        iv_dice1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.iv_dice1);
        iv_dice2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.iv_dice2);
        iv_dice3 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.iv_dice3);
        iv_dice4 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.iv_dice4);

        btnRoll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RollDiceFragment.this.rollDice();
            }
        });

        return rootView;




    }

    private void rollDice(){
        int d1 = this.random.nextInt(3) -1;
        int d2 = this.random.nextInt(3) -1;
        int d3 = this.random.nextInt(3) -1;
        int d4 = this.random.nextInt(3) -1;


        String print = (((BuildConfig.FLAVOR + addResult(d1)) + addResult(d2)) + addResult(d3)) + addResult(d4);
        int diceSum = ((d1 + d2) + d3) + d4;
        if (diceSum > 0){
            this.et_rollDice.setText("+" + Integer.toString(diceSum));
        }else {
            this.et_rollDice.setText(Integer.toString(diceSum));
        }

    }

    public String addResult(int i){
        if (i == 1){
            return "+";
        }
        if (i == 0){
            return "0";
        }
        return "-";
    }

}
```

The random roller works fine on the emulator and the result is shown in the editText line. I would just like the images to change based on the result of each dice. If a dice is showing a "-" the image shown should be diceminus.jpg.... Any help would be appreciated =)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are passing an int to setText method.

On the else case change it to using the setText overload with String as parameter:

```
this.et_rollDice.setText("" + Integer.toString(diceSum));
```

Comment: But how will this make "the images [...] change based on the result of each dice"? That's what the question is about after all

Comment: Yeah, sorry if I wasn't detailed enough. I have four imageviews of four dice. And the images should change with the individual dice result- so if a dice is showing "+" the image should be diceplus.jpg, if it is showing a "0" it should be dicezero.jpr and if the result is "-" it should be diceminus.jpg. I don't have any code for that here because I tried two methods and they didn't work so I erased them.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answers so I will post it here in case somebody else needs the code one day =)

switch (d1){
            case -1:
                iv_dice1.setImageResource(R.drawable.diceminus);
                break;
            case 0:
                iv_dice1.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicezero);
                break;
            case +1:
                iv_dice1.setImageResource(R.drawable.diceplus);
                break;
        }

```
    switch (d2){
        case -1:
            iv_dice2.setImageResource(R.drawable.diceminus);
            break;
        case 0:
            iv_dice2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicezero);
            break;
        case +1:
            iv_dice2.setImageResource(R.drawable.diceplus);
            break;
    }

    switch (d3){
        case -1:
            iv_dice3.setImageResource(R.drawable.diceminus);
            break;
        case 0:
            iv_dice3.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicezero);
            break;
        case +1:
            iv_dice3.setImageResource(R.drawable.diceplus);
            break;
    }

    switch (d4){
        case -1:
            iv_dice4.setImageResource(R.drawable.diceminus);
            break;
        case 0:
            iv_dice4.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicezero);
            break;
        case +1:
            iv_dice4.setImageResource(R.drawable.diceplus);
            break;
    }
```